# Are these two permutation matrices equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutation-matrices

**Definition:** The permutation matrix $P_{ij}$ is the identity matrix with rows $i$ and $j$ reversed. When left-multiplied with another matrix, it exchanges rows $i$ and $j$.

Am I right in thinking that $P_{12} = P_{21}$ because, in both permutation matrices, rows 1 and 2 are reversed?

In other words, does:

$$P_{12} \stackrel{?}{=} P_{21} \stackrel{?}= 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

**Answer: *Yes*.**

Comment: yes. you are correct.

Comment: Thanks. 8 more chars to go

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Jason, your intuition is correct:

$$P_{12} = P_{21}=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

just as in cyclic notation, we have the transposition $(1 \;\;2) = (2\;\; 1)$

Comment: Very clean response +1